# QTreeView show only parent directory, rather than parent and all its siblings

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I'm trying to get QTreeView (using an underlying QFileSystemModel) to show a directory tree.  If I set the RootPath to the parent directory, then I see all the children, but not the parent.  If I set the RootPath to be the parent's parent, then I see the parent directory with all its siblings.  Is there a way to get it to show the parent without its siblings, and all the children?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Linux. I'm not claiming it's the best implementation and I'm not sure if using backslash separators will work on Windows. I know Qt translates them to the native separator but I don't know if it's native separators that come out of the model's `data` method.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QTreeView>

class FilterModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
    FilterModel( const QString& targetDir ) : dir( targetDir )
    {
        if ( !dir.endsWith( "/" ) )
        {
            dir += "/";
        }
    }

protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow( int source_row
                                 , const QModelIndex & source_parent ) const
    {
        QString path;
        QModelIndex pathIndex = source_parent.child( source_row, 0 );
        while ( pathIndex.parent().isValid() )
        {
            path = sourceModel()->data( pathIndex ).toString() + "/" + path;
            pathIndex = pathIndex.parent();
        }
        // Get the leading "/" on Linux. Drive on Windows?
        path = sourceModel()->data( pathIndex ).toString() + path;

        // First test matches paths before we've reached the target directory.
        // Second test matches paths after we've passed the target directory.
        return dir.startsWith( path ) || path.startsWith( dir );
    }

private:
    QString dir;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    const QString dir( "/home" );
    const QString targetDir( dir + "/sample"  );

    QFileSystemModel*const model = new QFileSystemModel;
    model->setRootPath( targetDir );

    FilterModel*const filter = new FilterModel( targetDir );
    filter->setSourceModel( model );

    QTreeView*const tree = new QTreeView();
    tree->setModel( filter );
    tree->setRootIndex( filter->mapFromSource( model->index( dir ) ) );
    tree->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped quite a bit, and I'm able to get the results I was hoping for.

Answer (score -1):

The [example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtreeview.html#details) in description of `QTreeView` talks about calling `QFileSystemModel::setRootPath` but description of [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfilesystemmodel.html#details) talks of using `QTreeView::setRootIndex`. The document says:

> the contents of a particular directory
>   can be displayed by setting the tree
>   view's root index

Here is an example which worked for me. In this example when I wasn't calling `tree->setRootIndex(model->index((dir)))`, it used to show me list of all the directories and not `c:/sample`. Hope this helps.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
    QString dir("c:/sample");
    model->setRootPath(dir);
    QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView();
    tree->setModel(model);
    tree->setRootIndex(model->index((dir)));
    tree->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The question is whether you can show c:/sample with its children but without its siblings. Your code just shows the children of c:/sample.